# Objects created at the same time - unwanted compiler optimization?

Tags: c++11, timestamp, compiler-optimization, c++-chrono, g++4.8

I've got a weird problem:

```
for (size_t i=0; i<20; i++)
{
   // pre is a vector<UserType>
   pre.push_back(UserType()); // In UserType constructor, record std::chrono::steady_clock::now()
}
```

gives the following objects

> (gdb) print pre $1 = std::vector of length 20, capacity 32 =
>   {{timePoint_ = {__d = {__r = 1427724945979761000}}}, {
>       timePoint_ = {__d = {__r = 1427724945979761000}}}, {timePoint_ = {__d = {
>           __r = 1427724945979761000}}}, {timePoint_ = {__d = {__r = 1427724945979761000}}}, {
>       timePoint_ = {__d = {__r = 1427724945979761000}}}, {timePoint_ = {__d = {
>           __r = 1427724945979761000}}}, {timePoint_ = {__d = {__r = 1427724945979761000}}}, {
>       timePoint_ = {__d = {__r = 1427724945979761000}}}, {timePoint_ = {__d = {
>           __r = 1427724945979761000}}}, {timePoint_ = {__d = {__r = 1427724945979761000}}}, {
>       timePoint_ = {__d = {__r = 1427724945979761000}}}, {timePoint_ = {__d = {
>           __r = 1427724945979761000}}}, {timePoint_ = {__d = {__r = 1427724945979761000}}}, {
>       timePoint_ = {__d = {__r = 1427724945979761000}}}, {timePoint_ = {__d = {
>           __r = 1427724945979761000}}}, {timePoint_ = {__d = {__r = 1427724945979761000}}}, {
>       timePoint_ = {__d = {__r = 1427724945979761000}}}, {timePoint_ = {__d = {
>           __r = 1427724945979761000}}}, {timePoint_ = {__d = {__r = 1427724945979761000}}}, {
>       timePoint_ = {__d = {__r = 1427724945979761000}}}}

1, Theoretically, each of the 20 UserType objects should have different & unique time_since_epoch().count(), but in the gdb outputs, they're all the same.

2, I tried the same code here: http://melpon.org/wandbox and each object has a unique time stamp. So I'm observing different behaviours.

3, Some analysis: UserType() in pre.push_back(UserType()); is an rvalue; the compiler then value-copies(via copy constructor) the rvalue into an lvalue object in the vector pre. Is it possible that the compiler sees the constant loop number 20 and the rvalue object instructions, therefore decides to create 20 object "at the same time" as an optimization? Even if this is the case, it's not likely that the compiler can do construction all at the same time - there's no such thing as the same time - only small differences that can be ignored. I don't think the compiler can do 20 object constructions within 1 single tick of steady_clock.

4, Here's the relevant compilation flags in my Makefile - note that I did NOT ask the compiler to optimize: `-g -Wall -std=gnu++0x`

5, This piece of code(loop of 20 object constructions) was in a google test file; My compiler is g++ 4.8.3 on cygwin.

My questions is:

**What is going on here? Specifically, why am I seeing the same time stamps for constructing the 20 objects?**

Thanks a lot.

/*******************Per the request, UserType implementation*********************/

```
class UserType
{
    public:
    UserType()
    {
        timePoint_ = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    }

    bool operator==(const UserType other) const
    {
        return timePoint_ == other.timePoint_;
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, UserType type);

    protected:
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock> timePoint_;
};



std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, UserType type)
{
    out << type.timePoint_.time_since_epoch().count() << std::endl;
    return out;
}
```

Comment: Show the code for `UserType` it's possible you're not using `std::chrono::steady_clock::now()` correctly.

Comment: @b4hand I was. I once observed strange behavior(this pointer set to null when going into a function call) with google test on cygwin(it's a totally unrelated case), so to remove google test issues, I also tried moving the class into the main.cc and, I observed the same thing: same tick count for all 20 objects in gdb. This is a freaking weird thing...!

Comment: "I don't think the compiler can do 20 object constructions within 1 single tick of steady_clock." --- this assumption of mine was ridiculously wrong. Also, this statement itself is ridiculously wrong. The compiler generates assembly code and the linker generates the final binaries. The binary does the the construction, not the compiler. But you get my idea when I say "the compiler" does the the construction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've figured out the problem: I extended the 20 constructor calls to 2000 and I started to observe different time stamps on construction. That being said, a few hundred constructor calls were made within 1 nano second. This is brilliant.

Answer (score 0):

`std::chrono::steady_clock::now()` does not guarantee any specific resolution. It only guarantees monotonicity. Thus successive calls *can* return the same time. In fact, resolution may be sacrificed so that the monotonicity requirement is met.

If you want the highest possible resolution clock you must use [`std::chrono::high_resolution_clock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock).

`std::chrono::steady_clock::period` will tell you the length of a tick in seconds using a [`std::ratio`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/ratio/ratio).

Comment: I also tried std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000)) before each of the 20 constructions - I still saw the same tick counts. Really don't think the resolution can go beyond 1 second.

Comment: Why would you think the resolution *can't* go 1 second? The standard makes no such requirement.

Comment: 1, Speaking from a pragmatic point of view, no compiler vendor will be stupid enough to provide a stead_clock implementation with resolution > 1 second. In the world of electronics, 1 second is like 1 century for humans. 2, I tend not to use high resolution clock because there's no guarantee it's steady - this is a practical concern. 3, To make life easier, I just tried high resolution clock, and it was still giving me the same tick counts for all 20 construtions.

Comment: But thanks anyway for the input. I'm pretty sure the clock isn't the cause here.

Comment: Why speculate what you think when I told you how you could validate the *actual* resolution?

Comment: Period 1e-09
The code that generates this is: std::cout << "Period " << std::chrono::steady_clock::period::num / (double)std::chrono::steady_clock::period::den << std::endl;

Comment: Btw, same 1e-09 for high_resolution_clock